# Process a matrix in matlab without for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have got a matrix Nx3 dimension in matlab. I want to calculate the norm of every n-th row of the matrix. However I want to perform the norm calculation without using for loop. Is there a way to do so? My for loop code:

```
for i=1:length(accelerometer)
   magnitude(i,:) = sqrt(accelerometer(i,1)^2 + accelerometer(i,2)^2+   accelerometer(i,3)^2);
end
```

Comment: How do you define _magnitude of a row_? Do you mean magnitude of each number in that row?

Comment: The root of the sum of squares for every dim of the vector.

Comment: FYI: [norm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `A` be your matrix.

- If "every n-th row" means rows `1`, `n+1`, `2*n+1`,...:

  ```
  result = sqrt(sum(abs(A(1:n:end,:)).^2, 2));
  ```
- If it simply means "every row":

  ```
  result = sqrt(sum(abs(A).^2, 2));
  ```

In either case, if `A` is real you can remove `abs`.

Comment: Step n is not necessary.

Comment: @JoseRamon It seemed to be, from the wording in your question. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
x=[2 3 4;2 3 2;4 5 6];

magnitude=sum(x')';

ans =

     9
     7
    15
```

If x is complex at any point :

```
x=[2 3 4;2 3 2;4 5 6+1i];

magnitude_Complex=abs(sum(x')');


ans =

    9.0000
    7.0000
   15.0333
```

Comment: No is now what I want.

Comment: I don't understand. Does my solution is what you wanted ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake your solution doesn't return the same results with the one I have posted.

Comment: OK now i see what you mean, at the beginning this code wasn't there . Luis code seems like the right one at this case.

Answer (score 1):

The [`dot`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) function may also help you. Calling `A` your input matrix, and `n` the row step:

```
result = sqrt(dot(A(1:n:end,:), A(1:n:end,:), 2));
```

But note that if `A` is complex, the result will be complex, it's equivalent to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30731966/1507014) only for a real matrix.